# How do i use Drupal views to list all grand siblings of a node by taxonomy term

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I am trying to figure out how to display all grand-siblings of the current node as defined by a common navigation taxonomy in a block.

I can display all siblings of a node and all nodes using the taxonomy, but not all and only those nodes sharing the same grandparent taxonomy term.

I can create a view that filters by each individual grandparent, so I am assuming I need some way to wildcard that to say the grandparent of the current node rather than creating a separate view for each such taxonomy term on the site. There are only 35, so it is doable, but not exactly elegant, scalable, or easy to maintain.

Would the best place to do this be in the contextual filter, defining the "has taxonomy term (with depth)" output with PHP? This seems correct, but I haven't been able to find any sample code I can parse out well enough to edit for this purpose. Or is there some way to put wild cards against parent taxonomy terms in a simple filter field?

The View, as of my last poking, is as follows: [Link to image](http://www.daaq.net/images/views-page-menu.png) (apparently, I'm not allowed to post images yet).

Answer (score 2):

The answer was found here: [Finding cousins of a node in Drupal](http://mooseplum.org/2015/01/28/finding-cousins-of-a-node-in-drupal/).

Assuming you otherwise have a menu setup to connect nodes to their taxonomy terms for a menu in a node context:

In the **Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)** pane and do the following:

Under **When filter is not available**:

1. Select **Provide default value**.
2. Under the **Type** drop down, select **Raw value from URL**.
3. Select the depth of the Path component you want to use. For instance, if the node resides at /agents/php/installation/manual, then you would use 2 for cousins of that node.
4. Select **Use path alias**.

Under **When the filter value is available**:

1. Select **Specify validation criteria**.
2. Under the **Validator** drop down, select **Taxonomy term**.
3. Under the **Vocabularies** list select the taxonomy you are using for navigation.
4. Under the **Filter type** drop down, select **Term name converted to term ID**.
5. Select **Transform dashes in URL to spaces**.

This does cause problems with Clean URLs removing articles and particles from strings "Using the Widget" becomes "using-widget", but this can be circumvented by creating a Display Title field for taxonomy terms and using that for display while keeping taxonomy names short and clean.